# What filter is used on this image?

Tags: filter, image-processing

Can you please tell me what kind of filter is used on this image? Was this photo taken in black and white and then pinkish? And what is the easiest way to do this? (considering any program, like Photoshop)

[image]

Comment: That looks like a vector drawing, not a photograph that has been filtered. It may have started as a photograph (or multiple photographs), as a reference image, but the vectors are likely hand drawn.

Answer (score 18):

The filter is called a human. ;-)

The colors are so cleanly separated per depth layer, and the geometries are perfectly repetitive (eg the constant thickness of the beams) that this is human-made.

So, I guess somebody drew (including quite some copy & paste) the different silhouettes in a vector program (such as Adobe Illustrator). They probable used more than one photograph as a visual aid.
The 7 (?) layers were each colored in a single color and composited on top of each  other.

Comment: It actually looks like the same vector graphics on different layers with different scalings of the element and different color/opacity settings per layer.  The buildings look like the same graphic was used and the size  and placement was tweaked to show perspective

Comment: @DavidFass Where do you see reuse? At least the cranes are obviously all different, and if there are two building that only differ in size and placement and color, I haven't managed to find them.

Comment: Neither do I. But within each construction there is a lot of repetition, resulting in a somewhat off perspective.

Comment: The cranes, I now see are slightly different in look, although, some are obscured so it's tougher to tell...but the buildings look like the same building, that was scaled differently, making them 'fit' prospectively...and/or the  lines made thicker...all of the buildings have a similar shape, floors sticking out from a core structure and depending on where it is the core is more or less filled in.  Not sure how to describe it, but, Kris saw the 'repetition' which was what I alluding too

Answer (score 9):

That is most likely a vector drawing, and has most likely been vectorized by hand. It's possible some reference photos were used. I suspect it has been done by hand because the vectors are made up of perfect rectangles and lines.

Anyway, it's possible to create something similar to the example without hand drawing it. The easiest way is probably using vector software, such as Inkscape (free) or Adobe Illustrator (not free).

You could find some images and auto trace them. Auto tracing is not as good as creating vectors by hand, but it might be fine for something like this.  Once traced, fill with colour. Copy and paste various elements, scale and flip some horizontally, and fill with different colours to build up the design.

Here's an example made in Inkscape from just two photographs initially - the same could be done in Illustrator. This was made in just a few minutes. I'm pretty sure if you could put in a bit more time and effort you could do something much better.

[image]